# how can i access sessions on laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, session, laravel-5

i can access the `Session::get('LoggedUser')` on the index function with no problem.

[image]

but i can't access the session when i send an axios post request to the getProjects() function.

[image]

Controller code:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        //dd(Session::get('LoggedUser'));
        return view('user.project.dashboard');
    }

    public function getProjects(){
        dd(Session::get('LoggedUser'));
    }
}
```

compnent code:

```
mounted(){
            axios.post('/api/user/projects')
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(response.data.data)
                })
        }
```

api.php:

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function(){
    Route::post('projects',[UserProjectController::class, 'getProjects']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the withCrendetials option to true for the axios configuration

example configuration

```
const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: API_SERVER
})

window.axios = instance
```

check the boostrap.js file in your js folder you would see the configuration setting for you axios .. this is if you are using vue ui in your laravel setup